# Cannot get accelerometer sensor and GPS Location data in one activity, where is the problem?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, android-gps

I am trying to get GPS and accelerometer data at same time in one activity.
trying to save both of them in two different tables.
accelerometer data is ok and I saved it but after having location listener it doesn't work and GPS data is not provided.

Added permissions in MANIFEST.
Permissions seems to be ok.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor linearAccelerometer;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    public float a;
    public float b;
    public float c;
    private final static String TAG = "MainActivityTest";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Initilizing Sensor Services");

        //LOCATION
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS Value Changed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d(TAG, "Latitude is   "+location.getLatitude() + "    Longitude is    "+ location.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }

        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                },10);
            return;
        }
        }else
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 2000, 0, locationListener);

                }






        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
linearAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            // so we have accelerometer
            sensorManager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, linearAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sensor Registered ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Registered LINEAR ACC");
        }



    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sensor Value Changed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "X value is   "+ sensorEvent.values[0] + "    Y value is    "+ sensorEvent.values[1] + "    Z value is   " + sensorEvent.values[2]);


        //SQLITE INSERTATION
       Sensor sensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
       a = sensorEvent.values[0];
       b = sensorEvent.values[1];
       c = sensorEvent.values[2];

       if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            dbHelper.getInstance().insert(a, b, c);
       }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
}
```

NO errros. GPS data not provided.

Comment: Which Android version did you test this on?

Comment: It is tested on Emulator Nexus X5 API 28

Answer (score 0):

May problem is first, checking and get `permission` then register the `location listener`. Check the below link. Regards.

[stack overflow get user location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602557/how-to-get-users-location-through-gps-with-target-api-23-and-higher)

Comment: check these:   
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);

Comment: what if comment accelerometer sensor codes and check location call backs working or not ? (only location)

Comment: No, still no GPS data.

Comment: so the problem is about getting location and not related to accelerometer code.

Comment: Yes and that was my first question absolutely.